# Data not showing while automatically creating rows using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

while i am trying to display my data in html using ng-repeat its not displaying. I am trying to create rows dynamically. But the list is not getting displayed.

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('SearchBusController',['$scope','$sessionStorage','$http','$state',function($scope,$sessionStorage,$http,$state){
    var a="http://localhost:8080/business/allbusiness";
    $scope.BusinessList=[];
            $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:a,

    success:function(data){

    $scope.BusinessList=data;   
    console.log(data)
    },
    error:function(data){
        //alert("unsuccessfull");
        },  
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:"application/json",
});



    }]);
```

This is my html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SearchBusController">
    <table class="table1" cellspacing="0px" border="1"  width="60%;" style="background:white;">
    <tr ng-repeat="business in BusinessList">
    <td width="13%">
    <img src="images/welcome.jpg" style= "width:100%;" align="left">
    </td>
   <td colspan="2">
   <a href="">
    <p><span><h3 style="color:white;">{{business.BusinessDTO.company_name}}</h3></p></span></a>
    <a href=""> 
    <p><span><h3>{{business.BusinessDTO.address}}</h3></p></span></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
<table>
</div>
```

I am getting list in $scope.BusinessList which is

```
{"businessList":[{"BusinessDTO":{"businessId":1,"company_name":"Zafin","about_company":"asdasd"}},{"BusinessDTO":{"businessId":2,"company_name":"aaa","about_company":"hgfh"}}]}
```

any help??

Comment: use `$http` service to make API call instead of `$.ajax`, it will help you to keep UI in sync by running digest cycle.,

Comment: Yes use $http instead of $ ajax because when you use $ ajax the change happens out of the scope of angular an ugly way would be to call $scope.$apply(); inside your success callback after  $scope.BusinessList=data;  to manually fire apply but suggest you to use $http

Comment: but I need $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

Just try by updating your list assignment as below.

Replace following

```
$scope.BusinessList=data;
```

With

```
$scope.BusinessList=data.businessList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.BusinessList=data`.

Also please check your json objects. Your json isn't array. So you cannot use ng-repeat. It must be `BusinessList.businessList`.

```
{
      "businessList": [{
          "BusinessDTO": {
              "businessId": 1,
              "company_name": "Zafin",
              "about_company": "asdasd"
          }
      }, {
          "BusinessDTO": {
              "businessId": 2,
              "company_name": "aaa",
              "about_company": "hgfh"
          }
      }]
  }
```